# SFTP in Command line does nothing for a Server started in Android

Tags: linux, sftp

I started a sftp server in my android phone and trying to connect to it from terminal in  Linux. I changed the port in ssh_config as the application did not allow Port less than 1024. When I tried the 'sftp user@hostname' command, it does nothing. I'm able to type stuff after that but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The terminal]

Comment: Toss the [`-v` flag into that `sftp` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp) and it will get more verbose about what's happening during this attempt to connect. Also you note you changed the port on the android side(?) but I don't see that you specified the port in your `sftp` connection attempt. `sftp -v -oPort1024 user@hostname`

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the port on the SFTP command line

for Eg: sftp android@192.168.2.2 -P1024

And I recommend to not change the port in ssh_config